# Is it possible to use WinRT's CredentialPicker without a username?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

In a Metro Style app, I would like to use the WinRT provided CredentialPicker, mainly in order to provide a consistent look and feel for the user. However I only need a password, and not a username and password.

Is it possible to somehow hide the "User Name" entry box (as well as the user icon), but keep all other functionality when using Basic authentication?

Bascially I would like to have something like this:

```
using Windows.Security.Credentials.UI;

async Task<string> GetPassword() {
  CredentialPickerOptions options = new CredentialPickerOptions();
  options.ShowUsernameEntry = false; // Error: No such API

  var result = await CredentialPicker.PickAsync(options);
  return result.CredentialPassword;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. The only solution I see , is to create a custom dialog and design it like the `CredentialPicker`. Maybe you can also inherit functionality from the `CredentialPicker` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. you can't do that.